# Recommended way to use a python backend from a c#-application

Tags: c#, architecture, python, winforms

I have an old windows forms gui used to control a custom measurement system. Originally, it handled acquisition, calculating, database handling and presentation of measurements.

Now, because of some hardware changes, the system got its own arm based microcontroller running a linux os.

So I re-implemented most control features in python, including handling of our database and raw data. (Originally, everything was stored locally now it’s on a little server)

Now I still want to use our old gui to handle presentation so I thought of using some of my python implemented functions inside the gui application (C#). What would be the best/recommended way to do this?

Ideally, I want to use the gui for nothing more than displaying data and use the python routines to access the data itself on the server.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it might worth to take a look at IronPython

Comment: You could also look at Python.Included as a potential solution. See https://github.com/henon/Python.Included

Comment: You can find few solutions from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939357/communication-between-python-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/) might be a good fit for this as it will be pretty performant and fairly lightweight.  Alternatives include queues and even unix sockets.

Comment: Thanks I might go with gRPC, as we plan to move our db to one of our servers this could be a nice solution. So I can have a gui to present results and configure a series of measurements. A measurement system to perfor automatic measurements. And a db which can be used without the measurement system to be active. I'm not a software engineer so I nearly ended up doing everything with custom "raw" udp packages.